# Define a full method for a parameter expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I'm creating reports for a Report Server, and given that it lacks a code editor* to define full-bodied methods, any complex expressions used for setting properties can get very messy very quickly as they have to be a single statement. Usually that means a multi-layered nested `Iif(...)` bomb that ends in half a dozen closing brackets. Arbitrary fictional example:

```
=Iif(Fields!myField.Value == "Cancelled", 
    "It's been cancelled", 
    Iif(Fields!anotherField.Value < 15, 
        "Less than 15 things", 
        Iif(Fields!anotherField.Value >= 15 And Fields!anotherField.Value < 30, 
            "Between 15 and 30 things", 
            Iif(Fields!anotherField.Value >=30, 
                "Over 30 things", 
                "")))) 'keep hitting that close bracket key until things stop getting red squiggles
```

*Yuck*.

Is there something I can do to get a nice full method body in my expression editor? I know in C# at least some methods take either the name of an existing method or just let you write the method straight in there, but I don't know what that's called. That seems like the kind of thing I want here - a single expression with a method body "inside" it. I want to be able write expressions something like: (apologies for my dodgy VB.Net syntax)

```
= SomeMagic({
      If (Fields!myField.Value == "Cancelled") Then
          Return "It's been cancelled"
      End If

      If (Fields!anotherField.Value < 15) Then
          Return "Less than 15 things"
      End If

      If (Fields!anotherField.Value >= 15
      And Fields!anotherField.Value < 30) Then
          Return "Between 15 and 30 things"
      End If

      If (Fields!anotherField.Value ?= 45) Then
          Return "Over 30 things"
      End If
  })
```

If it's doable but only in C#, and it's possible to change the language used by the report to C#, I'm willing to accept that - I'm a lot more comfortable with C# than VB.Net. If there's a way to use a *competent** code editor with Report Server and define methods in there that can be called in the expression editor (and recognized by it), that's also an acceptable solution.

> *There *is* a code editor, technically. It's a dialog box. It's plaintext. It has no compile-time error checking. Methods defined in it aren't recognized in the expression editor. It's nearly useless.

Comment: I might be getting the name of Report Server / Reporting Services wrong. I mean the editor you use to actually create reports, that lives in that `Visual Studio Shell 2012 (Integrated)` thing that comes with Sql Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can either handle it IN **SQL** OR **SSRS**

**SSRS Way**: USE the `switch` STATEMENT.

```
= Switch(
      Fields!myField.Value = "Cancelled", "It's been cancelled",
      Fields!anotherField.Value < 15, "Less than 15 things",
      Fields!anotherField.Value >= 15 And Fields!anotherField.Value < 30, "Between 15 and 30 things",
      Fields!anotherField.Value>= 30, "Over 30 things"
      1=1, "Unknown"
  )
```

IN the `SWITCH` else is handled using 1=1 condition. IF you don't want else you can leave that part.

**OR** handle it in your **SQL query** which would be easier to maintain and debug.

```
  SELECT  Col1, Col2, ...
         CASE 
              WHEN myField = 'Cancelled' THEN 'It''s been cancelled'
              WHEN anotherField < 15 THEN 'Less than 15 things'
              WHEN anotherField BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN 'Between 15 and 30 things' --It includes both 15 and 30
              WHEN anotherField > 30 THEN 'Over 30 things'
              ELSE 'Unknown'
         END AS newColumn        
  FROM ...
  WHERE ....
```

Comment: The SQL way would be nicer in terms of maintenance, definitely, but when I'm using these for several properties across the report it feels *very* wrong to be doing that SQL-side. It would mean my report procedure having 15+ additional output columns called things like "DeptBackgroundColor", "DeptFontColor", etc etc, and potentially introducing a maintenance headache where some simpler expressions are worked out in RS whilst others are done in SQL. That feels very icky. Wasn't aware of the `Switch` function though, that's certainly nicer than my `Iif` nest.

Comment: Yes I agree if you have that many calculated columns then it might be better to handle in report than in query.

Comment: This is a great answer. The "custom code" editor in VS is ludicrous.